# deserialize cassandra row key

Tags: scala, serialization, cassandra, astyanax

I'm trying to use the sstablekeys utility for Cassandra to retrieve all the keys currently in the sstables for a Cassandra cluster. The format they come back in what appears to be serialized format when I run sstablekeys for a single sstable. Does anyone know how to deserialize the keys or get them back into their original format? They were inserted into Cassandra using astyanax, where the serialized type is a tuple in Scala. The key_validation_class for the column family is a CompositeType.

Comment: are you sure they are serialized? What do they look like? The example in the sstablekeys documentation at datastax (http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsSStabkeys_t.html) shows it returning what looks like the key hash.

Comment: They may be just hashed, example: 000c6d79496e636964656e74496400000575736572310000040000000100. I should note that I am using Cassandra 1.2, not 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [the comment by Thomas Stets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720500/deserialize-cassandra-row-key?noredirect=1#comment42046590_26720500), I was able to figure out that the keys are actually just converted to hex and printed out. See [here](http://shareitexploreit.blogspot.ca/2012/04/collecting-cassandra-keys.html) for a way of getting them back to their original format.

For the specific problem of figuring out the format of a CompositeType row key and unhexifying it, see [the Cassandra source](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/marshal/CompositeType.java) which describes the format of a CompositeType key that gets output by sstablekeys.  With CompositeType(UTF8Type, UTF8Type, Int32Type), the UTF8Type treats bytes as ASCII characters (so the function in the link above works in this case), but with Int32Type, you must interpret the bytes as one number.